# I can snap, bind and strap - What am I?

Tags: riddle, rhyme, homonym

I can snap, bind and strap,

Fight in wars, commit crimes,

I can be rubber or brass,

Hold together, and cut lines.

**What am I?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My guess is

> Band

I can snap,

> You can snap an elastic band.

bind and strap,

> Uses of bands are to bind and strap things together.

Fight in wars,

> Band of Brothers

commit crimes,

> Band of criminals (or perhaps Bandits)

I can be rubber

> Rubber band - a loop of rubber for holding things together.

or brass,

> Brass band - a group of musicians playing brass instruments.

Hold together,

> Band together - to form a group or unite.

and cut lines.

> Band(ing) cutters (thanks to Aggie Kidd in comments).

Comment: https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=band%20cutters

Comment: You're solving these too fast... >:/  +1

Comment: @AggieKid I was actually thinking saw but good one.  +1

Comment: "Cut lines" might also refer to a bandsaw.

Comment: cut lines could be an arm band that gets you to the front of the queue